# change links in tabular inlines not displayed after django-baton installed

Tags: django, admin, styling, django-baton

Change links, normally appear in each row in tabular inlines, not displayed after django-baton installed.

django 1.11
python 3.4
django_baton 1.1

show_change_link is correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the bug, I've filed it on github issues page (https://github.com/otto-torino/django-baton/issues/5) and fixed it in the new baton release.

Please upgrade django-baton to release 1.1.1.