# Horizontal radio fields support of django-baton in Django Admin

Tags: django, interface, admin, django-baton

radio fields defined as horizontal in Django Admin is displayed vertically after django baton installed. Will there be a fix for this issue.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this bug, it was fixed in release 1.1.2, please upgrade your django baton installation.

**Note**

I'm very glad you help me finding out bugs on this project. Just one thing. When you find something like this one or the other bug described here ([change links in tabular inlines not displayed after django-baton installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49929257/change-links-in-tabular-inlines-not-displayed-after-django-baton-installed?sem=2)), you'd rather file them in the proper issues page on github: https://github.com/otto-torino/django-baton/issues. While, if you need help on something, then this is the right place to go. Bye!